# In the Philippines, basically from what height is considered really tall for women?

Tags: philippine-citizens

In the Philippines, basically from what height is considered really tall for women? man's average is 5'4 so if she is over 5'4 basically judged so I think Do you think its correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is exactly the same question this OP previously posted on Travel.SE. It was off-topic for Travel, and it's similarly off-topic for Expatriates.

Comment: For the OP: the SE sites are not like others. Please take a look at the [Help pages](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how the site works, and what types of questions are appropriate.